# How to make vnstat display network statistics for ppp0 interface?

Tags: networking

I'm using `vnstat` on Ubuntu GNOME 13.10 32-bit to monitor my Internet usage. Running `vnstat` gives network statistics only for `eth0` and `wlan0`, but since I access Internet using a USB dongle, its network shows up as `ppp0` under `ifconfig`. How do I get vnstat to show network statistics for ppp0?

Answer (score 0):

After installing `vnstat` you need to create a database for your interface ppp0. Run the following command

```
sudo vnstat -u -i ppp0
```

> Force a database update for interface ppp0 or create the database if it doesn't exist. This is usually the first command used after a fresh install.
>   See [man page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/hardy/man1/vnstat.1.html)

Comment: I did it. But on calling `vnstat` it displays `ppp0: Not enough data available yet.`. I've used enough Internet for the data to be displayed.

Comment: Force update again `vnstat -u -i ppp0` then `vnstat  -i ppp0`, @nisargshah95

Comment: @nisargshah95 does it work ?

Comment: Nope. It still says `ppp0: Not enough data available yet.` even though I've used ppp0 for a day now. There should be something to show...

Comment: Show output of `ifconfig` @nisargshah95

Comment: here - http://pastebin.com/uEC5WK1k

Comment: @nisargshah95 Did you run the command as super user? Show the output of `ps aux | grep vnstat` and `vnstat`

Comment: Here http://pastebin.com/yEswNzJf @totti